# Why is the URI of albumart coded like this?

Tags: android

Why should we append an album art `Uri` in this manner:

```
final Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");

Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, album_id);
```

Why not this?

```
final Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart/"+AlbumID);
```

Edited: added "/" at the end of albumart in the second code block...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to do this other than convention; the initial question was looking for a solid reason such as memory, cpu time, or other resource savings--frankly it doesn't exist and the second block of code, despite adneal's short-sighted answer can be used on the fly as well--that's generally indicated by the use of a variable within uri construction.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off the second would be `...albumartID` whereas the first is `...albumart/ID`. But mostly because when you're fetching artwork it's usually on the fly and you don't know the ID of each album before hand.

Comment: Either solution would produce the correct uri once the typo is fixed, I think the op is asking why not use string concatenation.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Either produces the correct `Uri` after the typo is fixed, that's all that matters.

Comment: yeah, sorry that is just a typo...  missed the "/"....  i'm personally returning album_id from my mediastore query, so i just didn't understand why i would need to append...

Comment: i guess adneal's response leaves me with the question, "how is it that you return the album_id on the fly?" without storing it in some sort of array or list (which would completely obviate the need for any sort of appending...  it seems like a waste of space and time, both to the dev. in writing it and to the app in interpreting it for large numbers of list items), and does such a method cause issues in slowing down listview performance and/or decrease overall RAM requirements (less space needed to hold the list/array)?